# deleting history from google toolbar for ie

Tags: internet-explorer, history, privacy, google-toolbar

when I open a new tab, the google toolbar displays the most visisted pages. how can I control which pages appear there or remove them altogether?

Comment: you mean "from" not "form", correct?

Comment: @sculiffe, yes, fixed

Answer (score 2):

[Delete Internet Explorer search history from the Google Toolbar:](http://www.google.com/support/toolbar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9271)

[Watch a video on deleting search history from Internet Explorer.](http://javascript:toggleZippy('link2');toggleLayerDefault('detailsIE');javascript:urchinTracker('/support/outgoing/helpvideo-9271ie');)

- Click the Internet Explorer Tools menu, or press Alt-T on your keyboard.
- Select Delete Browsing History.
- Click Delete history and Delete forms.
- Click Close.